# Adding zombies, what order

Tags: dead-of-winter

It's stated in the rules that you add from 1 to 6 sequentially, but what I find unclear is if it is per turn or always.

Example (reduced to 3 entrances for simplicity)

z = zombie, - empty

Round 1 looks like

```
1 z--
2 z--
3 ---
```

adding 2 zombies the next round, should i start from 1 again and get

```
1 zz-
2 zz-
3 ---
```

or do i get

```
1 zz- 
2 z-
3 z--
```

Starting from 1 makes it easier to overflow since you start adding there each time, but seems most logical and easy to do. But not sure if i interpret correctly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer at the [rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/dead-of-winter/rules.pdf) it is explained that you always start placing the zombies at spot 1 when adding new zombies. Also of note if you have to add more then 6 zombies in a turn you cycle around from spot 6 to spot 1 again

> Whenever adding zombies, they are added 1 at a time until
>   all zombies that need to be added have been added.
>
> When adding zombies to the colony, always place the first
>   zombie on any empty space in entrance 1, the second zombie
>   on any empty space in entrance 2, the third zombie on any
>   empty space in entrance 3, etc. until all of the zombies that
>   need to be added have been placed. When adding a seventh
>   zombie, place it on any empty space in entrance 1 again, an
>   eighth zombie on any empty space in entrance 2, etc. If there
>   are no empty entrance spaces in the entrance the zombie
>   would be placed but there is a barricade token in one of
>   those spaces, destroy that barricade token and remove the
>   zombie that would have been placed. If there are no empty
>   spaces and no barricade tokens, the entrance has been
>   overrun, remove that zombie and kill the survivor at the
>   colony that has the lowest influence value. If there are only
>   helpless survivors at the colony, kill a helpless survivor. If
>   there are no survivors at the colony remove the zombie that
>   would have been placed without further effect. Every time a
>   survivor is killed (including a helpless survivor), decrease
>   morale by 1. When adding zombies to non-colony locations
>   follow all of the same rules, except there is only 1 entrance to
>   place zombies in so all of the zombies are placed in spaces at
>   that entrance.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that

```
1 zz-
2 zz-
3 ---
```

is the correct interpretation of the rules.  I'm not sure that it makes much difference, though, as long as you are consistent with the placement from the beginning, and everyone knows it, so they can predict (and eliminate zombies as necessary to prevent overflow).

Comment: How does this differ from the existing answer that explains that you always start at spot 1?